# Android - Adding objects to a list view from another activity

Tags: android, listview, parcelable

I've got a custom list view with my own adapter. I can add objects to this list within the same activity, but what I want to do is add objects from another activity. In this other activity there are two Edit Text boxes. One is responsible for Main text, second for Description, and two radio buttons that are determining image. At the bottom is Add button, that should add entered data to the list view.

I tried to do this with Parcelable, but I don't know exactly how to implement it. Below is my ListView class:

```
public class Activity_4 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listView;
private myAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_4);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView4);
    ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));
    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));
    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));
    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));
    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));
    objectList.add(new Object(R.drawable.row_img, "After Earth" , "2013"));

    mAdapter = new myAdapter(this,objectList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

public class Object implements Parcelable {
    int imageID;
    String mainText;
    String description;

    public Object (int imageID, String mainText, String description) {
        this.imageID = imageID;
        this.mainText = mainText;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Object() {

    }

    public int getImageID() {
        return imageID;
    }
    public void setImageID(int imageID) {
        this.imageID = imageID;
    }
    public String getMainText () {
        return  mainText;
    }
    public void setMainText() {
        this.mainText = mainText;
    }
    public  String getDescription() {
        return  description;
    }
    public void setDescription() {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Object(Parcel in) {
        this.imageID = in.readInt();
        this.mainText = in.readString();
        this.description = in.readString();

    }


    public final Parcelable.Creator<Object> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Object(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Object[size];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(imageID);
        dest.writeString(mainText);
        dest.writeString(description);
    }

}

public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    public myAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Object> list) {
        super(context,0,list);
        mContext = context;
        objectList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        Object currentObject = objectList.get(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
        image.setImageResource(currentObject.getImageID());

        TextView mainTxt = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_tv1);
        mainTxt.setText(currentObject.getMainText());

        TextView description = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.row_tv2);
        description.setText(currentObject.getDescription());
        
        return listItem;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can other `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()` and pass `data` in `bundle` as result on click of add button from other `Activity`, so current activity will add the data to it's list.

**Calling Other `Activity` to add**

```
startActivityForResult(intent,reqCode);
```

**On Result**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null && requestCode == reqCode) {
           Object object = new Object();
           object.setImageID(data.getIntExtra("image_id"));
           object.setMainText(data.getStringExtra("main_text");
           object.setDescription(data.getStringExtra("desc");
           objectlist.add(object);
           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

**Other Activity**

```
public void onAddClick(){
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.putIntExtra("image_id",*<value>*);
  intent.putStringExtra("main_text",*<value>*);
  intent.putStringExtra("desc",*<value>*);
  setResult(intent);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: I made it just like you said, values are taken from edit text, but only empty row is added (only picture is visible). Another question: after exiting the app, list is empty. How to save rows? Shared preferences or there is another way?

Comment: Modify setters in object model to pass string as paramter, I guess you were not passing strings and yea for small amount of data you can use sharedpreference but once it gets huge start using Database

Comment: I have one more question. I have also a main activity from where I can go into add activity and list view activity. Now I can only add objects from listview (by add button that directs to add activity), but I want also to add directly from add activity without entering the list view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point might be to start your EditText activity using [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and pass the updates to the list to your adapter through the result, after you added everything you wanted by calling [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) with your new data. For further reference see [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When opening 2nd Activity from 1st Activity

do

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(this,YourSecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(mIntent,SOME_STATIC_INT)
```

In another activity
on click of AddButton

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(this,YourFirstActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("DATA",Object)
setResult(SOME_STATIC_INT,mIntent)
```

now in 1st Activity 
Override onActivity Result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null && requestCode == SOME_STATIC_INT) {
           Object object = data.getParcelableExtra("DATA")

           objectlist.add(object);
           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```